# How do I backup my text messages off a SIM card under Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, smartcard, sim

I found monosim, but that only manages your contacts, and it works over PC/SC, which I believe is serial-based (I'd prefer a USB solution). Mainly, I'm wondering what software is out there, since everything I've seen is Windows-only. And I'm assuming any generic USB CCID smart card reader should work, or should I mainly look for [ones that are listed in the PCSC-Lite project](http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/supported.html)? Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for the ones listed as "supported" under the pcsc-lite/ccid project.

monosim should work just fine, there's a perl based application somewhere on the interweb (was it on the muscle site?) as well.

PC/SC does not say what the hardware is your reader is using. It can be serial, it can be USB, it can be PCMCIA.